# Cannot Obtain ListView position clicked in Context Menu

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a context menu, and do something to the line that was clicked in the ListView, but when ever I try to use `info.position`

Here is my code :

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); // The list view
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long id)  // One Long Click
        {
            registerForContextMenu(listView); // Registering the context menu
            Log.e(TAG, "Long Click!");
            return true;
        }
    });

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{      
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optmenu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.item3:
            RemoveTask(info.position);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

in `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, whenever I try to use the line info.position(suppost to return an int of the listview's position), the program just crashes...

(It doesnt get inside RemoveTask, I have chcked... even if I try to print `info.position` using Log, it crashes my application)...

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm using the same code as I posted here, yet suddenly, the menu isnt even showing up anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to register a View for a Context Menu, you do not need to set an `OnLongClickListener` for the View. In your case, the ListView can be registered for the Menu in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}
```

Get rid of the code for the `OnLongClickListener` and the rest of your code should remain the same:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optmenu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.item3:
            RemoveTask(info.position);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I dont understand, how does the Android knows I want to show the context menu only when I press a long click? or is it by default ?

Comment: Yes, that is the default behavior for context menus.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
registerForContextMenu(listView); // Registering the context menu
```

from your onCreate method right underneath

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); // The list view
```